# Cant shift Caesar Cipher by more than 1

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

I am new to Java and I have to make a Caesar Cipher program. This is my code. The problem I am having is that I cannot shift it by more than 1. For ex, if I write 'help me' and enter shift value of 2 it still only shifts by 1 --> 'ifmq nf'

```
  public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        String key;
        int keyLength;

        System.out.println("Enter message:");
        str=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter encryption key:");
        key=sc.next();
        keyLength=key.length();
        //This for loop is repeated use of 'Enrypt' and 'Decrypt' options
        for(;;)
        {
            System.out.println("1.Encrypt\n2.Decrypt\n3.Exit...");
            int choice=sc.nextInt();
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                /*send input string keyLength to encrypt() method to encrypt it returns 'Encrypted' string*/
                    System.out.println("Encrypted message..."+encrypt(str,keyLength));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //send retrived string from encrypt() method and keyLength to decrypt() method it returns 'Decrypted' string
                    System.out.println("Decryptedmessage..."+decrypt(encrypt(str,keyLength),keyLength));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //exit from the program
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option..");
            }
        }
    }
    public static String encrypt(String str,int keyLength)
    {
        String encrypted="";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            //stores ascii value of character in the string at index 'i'
            int c=str.charAt(i);
            //encryption logic for uppercase letters
            if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
            {
                c=c+(keyLength%26);
                //if c value exceeds the ascii value of 'Z' reduce it by subtracting 26(no.of alphabets) to keep in boundaries of ascii values of 'A' and 'Z'
                if(c>'Z')
                    c=c-26;
            }
            //encryption logic for lowercase letters
            else if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
            {
                c=c+(keyLength%26);
                //if c value exceeds the ascii value of 'z' reduce it by subtracting 26(no.of alphabets) to keep in boundaries of ascii values of 'a' and 'z'
                if(c>'z')
                    c=c-26;
            }
            //concatinate the encrypted characters/strings
            encrypted=encrypted+(char) c;
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
    public static String decrypt(String str,int keyLength)
    {
        String decrypted="";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            //stores ascii value of character in the string at index 'i'
            int c=str.charAt(i);
            //decryption logic for uppercase letters
            if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
            {
                c=c-(keyLength%26);
                //if c value deceed the ascii value of 'A' increase it by adding 26(no.of alphabets) to keep in boundaries of ascii values of 'A' and 'Z'
                if(c<'A')
                    c=c+26;
            }
            //decryption logic for uppercase letters
            else if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
            {
                c=c-(keyLength%26);
                //if c value deceed the ascii value of 'A' increase it by adding 26(no.of alphabets) to keep in boundaries of ascii values of 'A' and 'Z'
                if(c<'a')
                    c=c+26;
            }
            //concatinate the decrypted characters/strings
            decrypted=decrypted+(char) c;
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
```

Comment: `shift value of 2` - where is this coming from?  Is this the same as `key` if so the length of `1` and the length of `2` is the same

Comment: `key.length()` is returning the length of the `String` (so `1` would be `1` and `2` would be `1` etc); perhaps you should be using `Integer.parse(key)` or `Scanner#nextInt`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scary Wombat and MadProgrammer said, on line 12 you have `keyLength=key.length();`. This returns the *length* of the `String` you entered in. So if you enter in 2, `keyLength` is 1. If you enter in 11, `keyLength` is 2.

I would get rid of `keyLength` entirely, make `key` an `int` instead of a `String`, and set `key=sc.nextInt();`

This will allow 1 to be 1, 2 to be 2, and so on.

Remember to change all instances of `keyLength` to `key`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!