# Basic questions

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

I am new to Java and this a very basic question. This is a very small part of the program. Here is what I have to do:
User inputs a number (1-26) in `keyLength` as an encryption. If number is 1, `secretletter` would be a; if its 2 it would be b, and so on until z where it will be 26.

What I want to know is that, is there a better way than doing this:

```
if (keyLength==1){
    secretletter=a;
if (keyLength==2){
    secretletter=b;
```

What I have done is below, but my for loop is wrong and I always end up with z.

```
public static char secret(String str,int keyLength){
    char secretletter = 0;
    if (keyLength>=0 && keyLength<27){
        for(char i='a'; i<='z';i++){
            secretletter=i;
        }   
    }
    return secretletter;
}
```

EDIT: I found my mistake and @that other guy helped me as well

```
secretletter=(char)('a'+ keyLength - 1);
```

Comment: `char secretLetter = 'a' + keyLength - 1;`

Comment: Maybe also consider having a look at [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580795/cant-shift-caesar-cipher-by-more-than-1)

Comment: What you are doing is wrong. Hint: `String` is a `char`acter array.  So in the for loop try to change each character with the secretletter.

Comment: Relate the ASCII value to the key.

Comment: Hint: you can treat characters as integers representing their indexes in Unicode Table. So if you do `'a'+1` you will get `int` representing index of next character after `'a'` which is `'b'`. You can also cast `int` to `char`. No loops are needed.

Comment: @that other guy Thank you so much! I just realized and then you posted it as well!

Comment: Since your question is not really about loops use [edit] option to clarify it (especially title).

Comment: Your loop consecutively assigns a new value to `secretletter` (bad name because it violates the Java conventions), removing each preceding assignment's result in the process. Only the last assignment to `'z'` remains at the end. Also, the initialization to `0` is wasted, as that value is also immediately forgotten before it's ever used. At no point does the loop use the `keyLength` value to choose what gets assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for the switch statement.

```
public static char secret(int keyLength){
  char key;
  switch (keyLength) {
    case 1:  key = 'a';
      break;
    case 2:  key = 'b';
      break;
    case 3:  key = 'c';
      break;
    ........
    default: key = 'z';
      break;
  }
  return key;
}
```

Comment: (1) code-snippet is for code which can be actually run by browser, so this tool is for CSS/JavaScript/HTML examples. For Java use code-sample (`{}` icon in editors menu). (2) `char key = '';` will not compile since `''` is not valid character.